# I'm trying to List the most common occupation name ("Occupation") for each age range

Tags: survey, kaggle

But I'm getting a result like this.

'''python

In[ ] :

df = df['Occupation'].value_counts()[:11].sort_values(ascending=False)

df

Out[ ]:
Student                      5127

Data Scientist               2659

Software Engineer            1959

Other                        1720

Currently not employed       1645

Data Analyst                 1457

Research Scientist           1167

Machine Learning Engineer    1070

Business Analyst              786

Product/Project Manager       686

Data Engineer                 432

Name: Occupation, dtype: int64

My data is like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu11B.png)